# Intellij IDEA .class files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiled

Does the IntelliJ IDEA provide access to compiled “.class” files or decompiled “.class” files?  I’m enrolled in a course that requests for students to submit compiled “.class” files.

Comment: You can find them in your output directory, which should be named `out` or `target` or something like that. I'm not sure what you mean by compiled and decompiled .class files; there are only .class files, although you can decompile them to or compile them from .java source files

Answer (score -1):

IntelliJ does not produce any .class until you make your project

[Image showing how to make your project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DA6M.png)

After making your project the class files will be in Target folder:

[Image showing the class folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUYTM.png)